# Why Spark program is inconsistent and its not considering the complete input or number of records

Tags: apache-spark

My spark program is working fine and processing all the records properly when the input file size is small ~ 2GB. The same program when runs with 8GB its not considering all the input records and processing only 90% records.

I have tried changing the Spark Submit parameters but its not working. Please suggest.

Even the Spark UI is also showing the less number of records in "Input Size / Records:" field

spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn --executor-memory 6G --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 25 --class com.test.spark.etc

Comment: How do you read the input? How do you compare the records in the input and in the input file itself? More code...

Comment: My typo, it is "Inconsistent" not "consistent" in the question, I have corrected it now.
We are reading the input from the text file with delimiter and then parsing into fields. The code will look up in the Hbase table using field1 and get the corresponding value and then write into new file. I cannot share the code as its confidential but rather I can put into words or pseudo code

Comment: How do you count the number of records in a file and what Spark has read? What module do you use? Spark Streaming or Spark Core with RDDs?

Comment: I am checking in SPARK UI to see how many records and the size its considering and also I am validating with input after spark job is finished. Also I am doing "wc -l" for record count on actual input file. I am using Spark core with RDDs.

Comment: How do you read the file? Can you show the UI?

Comment: Below are the major parts of the code
===============================
val inp1 = sc.txtfile("input").persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
val sicd = inp1.mapPartitions(partition => { _some code_ }
val fin = sicd.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)

Comment: Can you replace `{ some code }` with `partition` to make sure it does not interfere with the number of records? You may skip rows intentionally.

Comment: I have tried but its not working.